# Set first oembed in post to a global variable or function

Tags: functions, shortcode, oembed

I have a function that gets the first oembed in the post.
I got the code from this related [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14853/73579).

```
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'my_function',10,4);
function my_function( $cache, $url, $attr, $post_ID ) {
  global $my_previous_post_id;
  if ($my_previous_post_id != $post_ID) {
    // post ID changed, so this is the first oembed for the post
    // do something with $url
    $my_previous_post_id = $post_ID;
  }
  return $cache; // it's important that you return the $cache value as-is
}
```

How can I get the first oembed from a post and make it a [global variable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables)? If that is not possible can we make the oembed url as post meta in order to access the first oembed anywhere?

I need to be able to access the first oembed in a loop within my shortcode.

You can get the first image in in a post (featured image) through a function:

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

You can get the first oembed in a post by:

```
???
```

@Otto wrote [how to get the first oembed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14853/73579) but how can we access it?

Comment: What is the `global` used for?

Comment: `<?php

function my_shortcode() {
 ob_start();
?>
<!-- Anything found here will be returned when called in a shortcode [my-shortcode] -->
<?php
 return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode('my-shortcode', 'my_shortcode');`

Comment: I am using ob_start() and ob_get_clean(); with my my custom shortcode to prevent it from hoisting to the top in the wp editor; I know about that already.

Comment: @s-ha-dum I am trying to access the first oembed from a post to use in a for each loop in my shortcode.

Comment: I am still not clear about the `global`. It isn't that WordPress "doesn't like them" exactly. It is that they are messy and very rarely actually necessary. But nonetheless, you set `global $embedCode` but you don't use it anywhere. I think you are going about this wrong but I am trying to get at the complete sequence of events, the complete logic. Can you sketch the logic from start to finish in words?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I have cleared up the question

Comment: So now you have raised another point: do you need the value "everywhere" or just when your Short code is use?  Why can't the sketchier game all of the logic? What is the short code code?

Comment: custom recent posts video carousel where I create a loop that displays the first video in a post.

Comment: the access "everywhere" statement means the same way you can access the_title(), the_excerpt(), or the_post_thumbnail of a post. I gave an example in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since WordPress 3.6+

There is a [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_media_embedded_in_content/) to print out all the media in the content.

```
get_media_embedded_in_content();
```